# File read from execve hooked LKM for validity checking in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a LKM which hooks sys_execve().

I would like to check if the execution file was altered or not for security reason using some integrity value.

Would you advise me how I can read the file to calculate the checksum in the hooked LKM module which is kernel level code?

Thank you.

//DAUM

Comment: Just open file in the kernel read its content and calculate checksum. What is a problem? You can also check actual implementation of this syscall.

Comment: The reason I'm afraid is that accessing a file in kernel level code is strongly not recommended even in this stack overflow. So, I'm worry about if there is a big side effect in kernel level code.

Comment: `accessing a file in kernel level code is strongly not recommended` - If you need to read content of the file, you have no other choice. Original implementation of `execve` syscall actually reads file for execute it. (It has no other choice).